# Compile-time detection of overflow in bitmask

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm toying with a general Bitmask class, based on [Type-safe Bitmasks in C++](https://gpfault.net/posts/typesafe-bitmasks.txt.html), and here is a minimum example highligthning my issue ([Compiler Explorer link here](https://godbolt.org/z/6Gh6c3s7E)):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<class EnumType,
     // Ensure that Bitmask can only be used with enums
     typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<EnumType>>>
class Bitmask
{
   // Type to store bitmask. Should possibly be bigger
   using underlying_type = std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>;

public:
   constexpr Bitmask(EnumType option) : m_mask(bitmaskValue(option))
   {std::cout << "Bitmask " << (int)m_mask << "\n";}

private:
  // m_mask holds the underlying value, e.g. 2 to the power of enum value underlying_type
  m_mask{0};
  static constexpr underlying_type bitmaskValue(EnumType o)
  { return 1 << static_cast<underlying_type>(o); }

  explicit constexpr Bitmask(underlying_type o) : m_mask(o) {}
};


enum class Option : uint8_t
{
   a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
};
enum class Option2 : int
{
   a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
};

int main()
{
    Bitmask<Option> b1{Option::a};
    Bitmask<Option> b2{Option::h};
    Bitmask<Option> b3{Option::i};
    Bitmask<Option2> b4{Option2::i};
}

// Output
Bitmask 1
Bitmask 128
Bitmask 0
Bitmask 256
```

In short, the Bitmask type works fine as long as the underlying type has more bits than the highest enum value used. If not, the bitmaskValue function will overflow and not give desired result, as shown in output, where b3 gets a value of 0, not 256.

I of course understand that an uint8_t cannot store more than 8 different bits, so what I want is some way to make this a compiler error, either when declaring `Bitmask<Option>`, or when instatiating a Bitmask with a too high value.

I tried changing the bitmaskValue method to:

```
   static constexpr underlying_type bitmaskValue(EnumType o) { 
   if constexpr (std::numeric_limits<underlying_type>::digits >= static_cast<underlying_type>(o)) {
       return 1 << static_cast<underlying_type>(o); 
   } else {
       // some error
   }
}
```

...but then I get the error that 'o' is not a constant expression.

Can anyone helpt me in the correct direction here? For the record, our project is currently using gcc 9.2/c++17, though I hope we can soon upgrade to gcc 11.1/c++20.

Thanks.

Comment: You can get a compile-time error only if the `Bitmask` object is (or rather must be) constant-initialized.  Is that useful?

Comment: I use a different approach to `bitmask` (more like a C bitmask). I don't know if my [implementation](https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/src/atd/atd_bit.h) can help you (look for `make_bitmask`). You can check a test [here](https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/src/atd/pc_test/bit/main.cpp)

Comment: Could you try to template the `bitmaskValue` function on the `EnumType` instead of passing it in as a parameter? `template <EnumType o>` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

As [Davis Herring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68055007/compile-time-detection-of-overflow-in-bitmask#comment120291383_68055007) already pointed out you cannot check for the overflow on a non-constant value at runtime (`constexpr` marked functions may also be executed at runtime). Thus to get the desired functionality one could check for the overflow inside the declaration of a template with the value to test as non-type template parameter.

The basic idea is that with [brace initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) with a constant value, the compiler will generate a compilation error when the cast is narrowing, e.g. `int8_t{128};` will fail since `128` cannot be represented with `int8_t`.

```
template<class EnumType>
class Bitmask
{
   using underlying_type = std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>;

public:
   explicit constexpr Bitmask(underlying_type v) : m_mask{v} {}
   constexpr Bitmask(EnumType option) : m_mask{0x1 << static_cast<underlying_type>(option)}{}

   template <EnumType option> // <- enum value as non-type template parameter
   static constexpr auto make() 
   {
        return Bitmask{underlying_type{0x1 << static_cast<underlying_type>(option)}};
   }
 
   underlying_type m_mask{0};
};
```

```
enum class Option : uint8_t
{
   a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
};

Bitmask<Option>::make<Option::f>(); // ok
Bitmask<Option>::make<Option::h>(); // ok
// Bitmask<Option>::make<Option::i>(); // will fail to build
```

https://godbolt.org/z/117baa4q4

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Unfortunately, this would break other parts of the class that I left out (to make a minimal example): see the addition of "or"-ing creation here: <https://godbolt.org/z/qxKdznGMe>

Comment: I of course understand that I cannot check for overflow on a non-constant at runtime, but this will mostly (only?) be used with values known at compile time, like he example I provided where e.g. `constexpr Bitmask<Option> b1{Option::a};` is known at compile time, but I still fail to check it.

Answer (score 1):

If you control the enum definition as well, the simplest way is just to require an enumerated constant with a fixed name at the end (ie, so it is the largest real value + 1), such as `EnumType::MAX_ENUM_VALUE`.

Then you can refuse to instantiate if

```
EnumType::MAX_ENUM_VALUE > std::numeric_limits<underlying_type>::digits + 1
```

with a static assert, or an enable_if, or whatever. Obviously this will also fail to instantiate if the enumerated constant is missing, so it should be pretty obvious to the user how to fix it.

Note this isn't really a compile-time check for overflow, but for the *possibility* of overflow. So, it is on the strict side if you only use a subset of your enum's values - but it is consistent with the goal of type safety.

Comment: Thanks, I got this working: <https://godbolt.org/z/n9Wz44r5Y>, and may even use it, though I have three issues with this: 1 (I didn't get static_cast to work inside enable_if, and had to use c-style-cast), 2 (Having to declare the maxValue enum is sub-optimal), 3 (The compiler error is completely unreadable). Still the only solution so far if I want the check.